# How to get clickable div and ajax load working together

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, click

UPDATE 4:

I have a horrible feeling that this has slipped so far down that no one is seeing it anymore...but just in case...

I am trying to combine the clickable div code and the ajax load code (see main code block below) Everytime I add the clickable div code the load stops working. I have tried:

```
$(".work").on('click',function(){
  window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
});

$('.work a').on('click',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
 etc
```

this

```
 $('div.work').on ('click',function(event) {

    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");

    $(this).attr("href"); event.preventDefault();
```

and many other permutations - but they ALL stop the .load working

Have run out of ideas and getting desperate - please....

UPDATE 3:

Still struggling with this...

UPDATE 2

As the answer below keeps getting votes (even though I am not sure why it's applicable...) I have tried the following: First I updated to jQuery 1.7.1 and used .on for the clickable div code:

```
$(".work").on('click',function(){
  window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

that made no difference so I tried applying it to the ajax load code as well:

```
$('div.clickable, .work a').on('click',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
etc
```

that made no difference either...

Would really appreciate an explanation as to why .live (.on) is applicable in this case when I am not trying to affect anything loaded by the ajax... clearly at least 4 members think it is...

UPDATE:

In case it helps you can see the 2 different versions below. The first shows the ajax load happening. The second simply adds the code for the clickable div, which stops the ajax load from working:

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/ajaxload.html

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclick.html

ORIGINAL POST:

I have a div element (.work) that contains an h3 tag, which contains an anchor, which loads ajax content into another div (.pictures) when clicked.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="work">
 <img class="introPic" src="images/thumb.jpg" width="250" height="99" />
 <h3><img class="arrow" src="images/arrow_open.gif" alt="&gt;" /><a class="titlelink" href="project2.html">Project 2</a></h3>
  <div class="projectIntro">
    <p>This is some intro text for project 2</p>
  </div>
 <div class="pictures"></div>
</div>
```

I have the ajax load working fine using this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
// Adds the open and close effect for anchor links showing work.    

$('.work a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();     

    var parent = $(this).parents(".work");
    var content_holder = parent.children(".pictures");

    if (parent.hasClass("selected_work")) {
        close_other();
        return;
    }

    close_other();

    parent.addClass("selected_work");

    content_holder.load(this + " #ajaxContent", function() {
        $(this).find('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    animSpeed:300,
    pauseTime:4000,
    controlNav:true,
    pauseOnHover:true //Stop animation while hovering
});
     });

    $('.selected_work img.arrow').attr("src", "images/arrow_close.gif");
});

function close_other() {
    var selected_work = $('.selected_work');

    selected_work.children('.pictures').empty();    
    $('.selected_work img.arrow').attr("src", "images/arrow_open.gif");
    selected_work.removeClass("selected_work")
}

$('.work a.titlelink').click(function() {
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 500);
     });

});
```

Now I want to make the entire .work div clickable and I have found some code that I've got working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var block = $(".work");
  block.click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).find("a:first").attr("href")
   });
   block.addClass("clickable");
   block.hover(function(){
     window.status = $(this).find("a:first").attr("href")
   }, function(){
      window.status = ""
   })
});
```

For some reason I couldn't get the shorter and more common version of the clickable div code working... this is not my main problem but it would be good if anyone could tell me why:

```
$(".work").click(function(){
  window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
});
```

My main problem is that although I can get the clickable div code and the ajax load code working individually, I can't get them working together. If the clickable div code comes first, the anchors link to new pages rather than loading them into the same page. And if the ajax load code comes first, the clickable div code is ignored...

I also want to ensure that my scroll still works when the .work div is clicked, as it does when the h3 link is clicked - ie this bit of code:

```
$('.work a.titlelink').click(function() {
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 500);
     });
```

Hopefully a kind member of the community can help me out with this one!

thanks

Comment: There is one difference in the code you gave (not sure if it is an accident).  `block.click(...` doesn't return false and `$('.work').click(...` does return false. Have you tried removing that in the "shorter, more common version."

Comment: Thanks Andrew - that fixed that problem (it was an accident) - shorter code now working in terms of making the div clickable - but no difference in terms of getting clickable div and ajax load working together...

Answer (score 6):

I think the issue is that you are binding the "click" events to elements that don't exist yet -- that only exist after the ajax load. Am I right?

In this case, you need to use jQuery's 'live' method

> This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers **when content is dynamically added to a page.**

eg:

```
$(".work").live('click', function(){
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, you can use .on() which is the main function for all the alias functions such as .live(), .delegate & .bind().

Comment: Thanks - but I don't think that's it if I have understood you correctly - the click events are bound to .work which exists before the ajax load - in fact it is this click that triggers the load.

Comment: To be clearer, the ajax load is currently triggered by a click on an anchor within .work (.work a) - What I now want is for the ajax load to be triggered by a click on the .work div itself. Both the .work div and the anchors within it exist before any ajax load.

Comment: As this answer has been voted up twice, I tried it but it hasn't made any difference. If someone who thinks this is right could explain why I would appreciate it... I can't see how I am trying to bind click events to elements which don't exist yet - which elements exactly?

Comment: hmmm - another vote for this answer which I don't understand...here is a version with the .live implemented as suggested above - it is not working: http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/clicktest/divclicklive.html

Comment: OK - that's another vote for this answer.. Once again I ask anyone who thinks this is right if they could please explain how I am "binding the "click" events to elements that don't exist yet -- that only exist after the ajax load" - which elements exactly? I can't see how I am trying to bind click events to any elements that only exist after the ajax load - I am trying to bind them to .work which exists before the ajax load... Not to mention I have tried this and it's not working.

Comment: @eschwartz - appreciate you trying to help, but would appreciate some clarification - thanks.